# How to add a class to the <a> tag in Yoast SEO breadcrumbs?

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs, yoast

I am using [Yoast Wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) and the breadcrumb function that it provides. It works great, but I want to modify the default structure and to add an additional class.

So instead of:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Home</a>
```

I want to make it:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="my-class" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try Below Code in your function.php file in which you can add custom class to breadcrumb.

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link', 'ss_breadcrumb_single_link', 10, 2 );
function ss_breadcrumb_single_link( $link_output, $link ) {
$element = '';
$element = esc_attr( apply_filters( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link_wrapper', $element ) );
$link_output =  $element;

if ( isset( $link['url'] ) ) {
    $link_output .= '<a rel="nofollow" href="' . 

 esc_url( $link['url'] ) . '" rel="v:url" property="v:title" class="my-class">' . 

 esc_html( $link['text'] ) . '</a>';
 }
 return $link_output;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your example modifies the last item to <a> tag instead of <strong> tag. Based on your function I used **str_replace()** to add my custom class ```add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link', 'ss_breadcrumb_single_link', 10, 2 );
function ss_breadcrumb_single_link( $link_output, $link ) {
 return str_replace('<a', '<a class="my-class"', $link_output);
}```

Answer (score 2):

Your comment works.

```
//add class to yoast breadcrumb link
add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link', 'change_breadcrumb_link_class'); 
function change_breadcrumb_link_class($link) {  
    return str_replace('<a', '<a class="my-class"', $link); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add a breadcrumb name specific CSS class to each link, you could use the fallowing:

```
/**
     * Helper function which will generate a valid CSS class 
     * from a breadcrumb link text name.
     *
     * @param string $string 
     * 
     * @return void 
     */
    function cleanString($string)
    {
        $string = remove_accents($string); // WordPress internal function
        $string = strtolower($string); // convert to lower case
        $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
        $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
    
        return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string); // Replaces multiple hyphens with single one.
    }
    
    /**
     * Modifies SEO Yeast breadcrumbs links through wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link filter
     *
     * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178688/how-to-add-a-class-to-the-a-tag-in-yoast-seo-breadcrumbs
     *
     */
    add_filter('wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link', 'ss_breadcrumb_single_link', 10, 2);
    function ss_breadcrumb_single_link($link_output, $link)
    {
        $classText = cleanString($link['text']);
        return str_replace('<a', '<a class="breadcrumbs-' . $classText . '"', $link_output);
    }
```